# Cannot Install Scrapy On my mac

Tags: python, macos, scrapy, pip

I am currently using Mac OS X 10.11.1 El Capitan. I installed both python 2.7 and 3.5 on my mac. I also installed pip. However, i always fails to install scrapy on my mac.

I used

```
$sudo pip install scrapy
```

and it always finds an error. 
(like this)

```
 1 error generated.
Compile failed: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
creating tmp
cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /tmp/xmlXPathInitOS_E4M.c -o tmp/xmlXPathInitOS_E4M.o
/tmp/xmlXPathInitOS_E4M.c:1:10: fatal error: 'libxml/xpath.h' file not found
#include "libxml/xpath.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
*********************************************************************************
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
Perhaps try: xcode-select --install
*********************************************************************************
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

and this..

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-veAN2s/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-8tLCDw-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-veAN2s/lxml
```

Can anyone please tell me what the problem and the solution is?

Comment: I hava Anaconda and get the following Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: ...........[                    ]|                                                  |   0%
[      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%



Error: Unsatisfiable package specifications.
Generating hint: 

Hint: the following packages conflict with each other:
  - scrapy
  - python 3.5*

Comment: The error message asks a question you may want to answer: `Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?`

Comment: scrapy doesn't support python3

Answer (score 10):

```
xcode-select --install
```

You probably haven't updated code command line tools since upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your MacOS linked with its default Python2, which in turn misses appropriate GCC flags to compile Scrapy.

I suppose you've installed Homebrew, then do the following:

1. Install Homebrew python:
   `brew install python`
2. Update pip setuptools:
   `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools`
3. Now, it should be fine:
   `pip install scrapy`

Answer (score 1):

After trying all above and still failed here's mine if you're using Mojave and pypy3 virtual environment :

```
(env)$python -V
Python 3.5.3 (fdd60ed87e94, Apr 24 2018, 06:10:18)
[PyPy 6.0.0 with GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)]
(env)$ pip -V
pip 18.1 from xxx/xxx/pip (python 3.5)
```

point these:

```
export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
```

Source:

https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/3489

Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Give `easy install` a try. I had difficulty in installing `scrapy` after installing and uninstalling Python 3.  `easy install` solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

1. please try these commands:

> sudo
>   C_INCLUDE_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/libxml2
>   :/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml
>   :/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include
>   pip install scrapy  --ignore-installed six

2. close SIP(system Integrity Protection)
   -- then reboot, use command +R to enter debug mode, then select terminal:
   csrutil disable
   reboot
3. reinstall six
   -- then remove old six, install it again

   sudo rm -rf /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/six*

   sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six*

   sudo pip install six

then scrapy works